Automated export of a SharePoint list, with multi selected choices columns
I have a SharePoint list that contains 8 text columns and 4 multi selected choice columns. and I want to automate a daily export via power automate. find my flow down below.
The problem is I don't know how to deal with those columns in the SELECT action. I tried this function:
join(item()?['ColumnName'],', ')}

But it's returning an object. I also tried to add ?['Value'] after the column name, it's still doesn't return the value.
join(item()?['ColumnName']?['Value'],', ')}

Any help please?


Since multi-select column values are returned as an array of objects, we can't directly use join() function in [Select] action to create a string. But with some additional steps, we can create a CSV table from SPO list items. See the screenshots below for details.
In the example, [FavoriteColors] is a multi-select choice column

Output


Thank @MatiurRahman, your provided solution works perfectly !
